# Local isomorphism question in logics

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

The definition of a local isomorphism between structures:

> a local isomorphism between structures $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ over an alphabet $L$ is a finite relation  $$\{ (a_1,b_1),...,(a_n,b_n)\} \subset A \times B $$ 
>   such that the simple extensions $(\mathcal{A},a_1,...,a_n)$ and $(\mathcal{B},b_1,...,b_n)$ are elementary equivalent.

In a Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé game the goal of the duplicator is to make a local isomorphism. Between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$. 
A theorem of these games is that  $$\mathcal{A} \equiv^n \mathcal{B} \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{A} \sim_n \mathcal{B} $$ 
We have if $\mathcal{A} \sim_n \mathcal{B}$, then $(\mathcal{A},a_1,...,a_n)$ and $(\mathcal{B},b_1,...,b_n)$ are elementary equivalent.
But doesn't this mean that also $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are equivalent and so the previous theorem doesn't say anything in the $\Leftarrow$ direction?

Comment: Where did you find this definition of local isomorphism? The usual definition is that $(\mathcal{A},a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $(\mathcal{B},b_1,\dots,b_n)$ satisfy the same _quantifier-free_ sentences.

Comment: Yeah thanks, apparently my book gives the wrong definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long Comment*

It seems to me that the symbolism for *local isomorphism* is not so "stable"; thus, I'm not sure about the equivalences...

I'll refer to :

- Jouko Vaananen, [Models and Games](https://books.google.it/books?id=uDDDbkfZpIEC&pg=PA81) (2011), page 81-on.

We have :

> $\mathcal{A} \equiv \mathcal{B}$, i.e. *elementary equivalence*, when the two structures satisfy the same FO sentences,

and :

> $\mathcal{A} \equiv_n \mathcal{B}$, when they satisfy the same FO sentences of quantifier rank $\le n$.

Next we have [page 69] :

> $\mathcal{A} \sim^n_p \mathcal{B}$ if there is a back-and-forth sequence of length $n$ for $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.

Some results :

- page 70 :

> **Proposition 5.27** The following are equivalent:
>
> > 1. $\mathcal{A} \sim^n_p \mathcal{B}$
> > 2. **II** [Duplicator] has a winning strategy in $\text{EF}_n(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$.

- page 81 :

> **Proposition 6.4** Suppose $L$ is an arbitrary vocabulary. Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are $L$-structures and $n \in \mathbb N$. Consider the conditions:
>
> > *(i)* $\mathcal{A} \equiv_n \mathcal{B}$
> >
> > *(ii)* $\mathcal{A}\upharpoonright_{L'} \sim^n_p \mathcal{B}\upharpoonright_{L'}$ , for all finite $L' \subseteq L$.
>
> We have always *(ii)* $\Rightarrow$ *(i)* and if $L$ has no function symbols, then *(ii)* $\Leftrightarrow$ *(i)*.

Thus, "cooking all together", It seems to me that :

> if $\mathcal{A} \sim^n_p \mathcal{B}$, for all $n$, then $\mathcal{A} \equiv \mathcal{B}$, i.e. $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are *elementary equivalent*.